# Linkable columns in list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, web-part, hyperlink

I have a web part which shows items from a list. I want one of the column to be a hyperlink for the item.

Let's say column: First Name, and when user clicks one of the items in a column First Name to redirect him to the full information of the person Ivan(for an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that sometimes there are problems with just making linkToItem = "True" in the allItems.aspx.

So I tried the powershell way to do it and the result was positive ! It takes little more time but works perfectly ! Here you can see how to do it :
http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.bg/2013/05/simple-concept-list-view-how-to-add.html

Sample:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb siteURL
$list = $web.GetList($web.URL +"URLToTheList\AllItems.aspx")
$Flds = $list.Fields;
$Flds.SchemaXml >> NameTheFileAsYouWant.txt
$Fld = $Flds.getField("TheFieldWhichYouWant")
   /*open NameTheFileAsYouWant.txt. Copy the content over to the notepad.
Add attributes LinkToItem="TRUE" LinkToItemAllowed="Required" 
ListItemMenu="TRUE". 
Replace '"' with '''.Copy content
   */
$Fld.SchemaXml ="{your copied edited field caml}"
$Fld.Update()
$list.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list on **SharePoint Designer**
2. Search for the **ViewFields** tag
3. List item `LinkToItem="TRUE"` to whichever column you want the link:

`<ViewFields><br/>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><br/>
    <FieldRef Name="linkThisColumn" LinkToItem="TRUE"/><br/>
    <FieldRef Name="Column 1"/><br/>
    <FieldRef Name="Column 2"/><br/>
</ViewFields><br/>`

Comment: I have added it, I tried with linkToItem too,because in some forums I have found that it is causing problems if its with capital L,  but still it's not working..